Mapping Reflection Principle
I'm reading this paper written by Moore and he mentions the notion of a continuous $\in-$chain.
Can anyone tell me what he means by that? I can't find the definition

The link for the original paper is here: https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0501526.pdf

Isn't it something like here(but with $\in$ except of $<_{I_j}$)?  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4593967/continuous-chain-of-kappa-isomorphic-linear-orders-on-kappa-ge-aleph-1

It looks like it is! Thanks I'll take a look

But, In that case, the principle should say $\in-$ continuous, isn't it?

A continuous $\in$-chain $\langle N_\nu:\nu<\omega_1\rangle$ is a sequence of sets $N_\nu$ that, first of all, is an $\in$-chain, meaning that whenever $\alpha<\beta<\omega_1$, we have $N_\alpha\in N_\beta$ and, second, at limit ordinals $\lambda<\omega_1$, we have that $N_\lambda=\bigcup_{\alpha<\lambda} N_\alpha$. Note that this second condition requires that if $\alpha<\lambda$, then $N_\alpha\subset N_\lambda$, rather than just $N_\alpha\in N_\lambda$ as required by the first condition.
In the case at hand, the models $N_\alpha$ are countable elementary substructures of $H(\theta)$, a model of enough set theory, which means that this extra requirement is actually satisfied: if $N_\alpha\in N_\beta$, then $N_\beta$ sees that $N_\alpha$ is countable (since $H(\theta)$ sees that $N_\alpha$ is countable, and $N_\beta\prec H(\theta)$). This means that there is, in $N_\beta$, a surjective map $f:\omega\to N_\alpha$. Since each $f(n)$, $n\in\omega$, is definable from $f$, each such $f(n)$ is an element of $N_\beta$, and therefore $N_\alpha\subseteq N_\beta$ (regardless of whether $\beta$ is a limit ordinal).

Thank you so much!
